# How to add Hyperlink to adaptive cards

Tags: adaptive-cards

I want to add hyperlink to adaptive card. I am using markdown features of Text block for it. I have below adaptive card. I referred to the below link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features#:~:text=localizing%20the%20text.-,Markdown%20(Commonmark%20subset),of%20the%20Commonmark%20Markdown%20syntax.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features#:%7E:text=localizing%20the%20text.-,Markdown%20(Commonmark%20subset),of%20the%20Commonmark%20Markdown%20syntax.)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This is some **bold** text"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This is some _italic_ text"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "- Bullet \r- List \r",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "1. Numbered\r2. List\r",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "[Adaptiveards](https://adaptivecards.io)"
        }
    ]
}
```

But in visualizer the hyperlink is not working. How to add a hyperlink to adaptive card?

[image: Visualization Result]